# How can I get the values in my file without fopen

Tags: c, file

I need to access the values from my txt file but I cannot use fopen or fclose or fsacnf. I need to use ./a.out<text.txt

the values are: 1,5,6,15,24,56,34,12,34.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 20

int input[SIZE];


int main()
{
   int count;

   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
  {    
      printf("%d\n",count);
      count++;
  } 
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I am doing this on bash

Comment: `stdin` is open already; that will be where the `text.txt` goes. You have already included `stdio.h`; something [in there](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdio.h.html) will probably do nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using input redirection, then they'll be available on the input stream, not via a file handle you have to open.

Hence you can use `scanf` to get them. Assuming they're just a sequence of integers separated by white space<sup>(a)</sup>, this will be a good start:

```c
int value;                              // Need variable.
while (scanf("%d", &value) == 1) {      // Returns 1 if successful.
    printf("Got %d\n", value);          // Progress messages.
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I'm assuming here that the commas in your number list are merely separators in the *question*  to distinguish the numbers from each other (i.e., they're not in the file itself).

If they actually exist *in* the file, then they'll need to be consumed as well.

Comment: @SaugatUpadhaya: simplified the code to just print the numbers rather than accumulate them.

Comment: You need to consume the commas in the input stream.

Comment: @William, it's not clear whether those commas are in the input stream or simply textual separators in the question for the values in the stream. The wording suggested the latter to me since it talks about the values (plural), not the format (singular). I'll clarify ...